Why alertmanager is re-sending notifications after (group_interval + repeat_interval) duration?
Alertmanager notifications are delayed. Alertmanager re-sends notifications after (group_interval + repeat_interval) time. We are expecting the notifications to be re-sent after repeat-interval time for an alert which is still active.
We have following configuration:
group_wait: 10s
group_interval: 2h
repeat_interval: 2h
When the alert rule condition is met, Prometheus waits for 30 minutes before firing an alert. After 30 minutes, alert gets fired and alertmanager sends initial notification after 10 seconds of group_wait time. All of this works fine till this step but then next notifications for the same alert get re-sent after every 4 hours. We are expecting to be sent after every 2 hours as per configuration of repeat_interval. There is no change in alert state and there is no new alert in the same group.
If we configure both, group_interval and repeat_interval with value 1h, initial notification is sent in 10 seconds but next notifications for the same alert are re-sent after every 2 hours instead of 1 hour.
After trying below configuration, next notifications are re-sent after 1 hour 30 minutes instead of 1 hour.
group_interval: 30m
repeat_interval: 60m or 1h
So it looks like alertmanager considers the duration of (group_interval + repeat_interval) to re-send the next notifications instead of repeat_interval. Wondering why this could be happening, I will appreciate if someone can explain the reason and possibly provide a solution. Thanks in advance.

This looked like an interesting question so I spent some time on this by going thru doc and code.
Doc - https://github.com/prometheus/alertmanager/blob/cad5fa580108431e6ed209f2a23a373aa50c098f/docs/configuration.md
group_wait, group_interval and repeat_interval used in this context. Ideally repeat_interval is what should the open alerts should repeat for. But as per the code (snippet below), it does wait for group_interval as well (line 460) every time for reset purpose.
https://github.com/prometheus/alertmanager/blob/cad5fa580108431e6ed209f2a23a373aa50c098f/dispatch/dispatch.go#L441-L468
In the examples, they have mentioned group_interval as minimal (around 5m) for grouping purpose I guess. But repeat interval is 1h or so (and also it should be in multiples of group interval).
So overall, the behavior seems to be correct based on the code though its not very clear in the docs.
